# How add text in specified position to already existing file

Tags: maxscript

I try to add text to a specified position to already existing file. When i run my code new text added at the end file and not in the specified position. what did i do wrong?

```
fs=openFile "c:/my.txt" mode:"a+"
skipToString  fs ";"
seek fs (filepos -1)
format "add new text" to:fs
close fs
```

му.txt content

```
levl_name        # tech_lvl,military_lvl,desert_lvl;
body        # Column,Pilaster,Plinth,Wall_,Floor_;
prefix1        # _left_,_right_,_top_,_bottom_;
prefix2        # _bad_, _good_,_Tall_, _Low_;
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to convert to a stringStream, do all your work in there and simply overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the reference explicitly says: *'When a file is opened with one of the "a" access types, all write operations occur at the end of the file. The file pointer can be repositioned using seek, but is always moved back to the end of the file before any write operation is carried out.'*

Also, writing to the stream would overwrite the contents, you'd have to get everything from that position to the end of file, save it, do your edits and paste that again, something like

```
file = @"c:\my.txt"

ms = MemStreamMgr.openFile file
size = ms.size()
MemStreamMgr.close ms

fs = openFile file mode:"r+"
skipToString fs ";"
pos = filePos fs - 1
seek fs pos
previousContent = readChars fs (size - pos)
seek fs pos
format "add new text" to:fs
format previousContent to:fs
close fs
```

If you can change the file format, consider using INI/XML files, it's much easier working with them.